# Can Xcode8 customize a toolbar depending on size classes?

Tags: uibarbuttonitem, xcode8, traits, size-classes

I want, using the storyboard, to add a `UIBarButtonItem` to a `UIToolbar`, but only for `width:Regular` and `height:Regular` devices.
In the bottom of the storyboard, I activate „**Vary for Traits**“, and select width and height, so that only iPad devices remain.

If I draw an `UILabel` to the canvas, the attributes inspector shows me, as expected, 2 „installed“ fields, one for all devices (unchecked), and one for `wRhR` devices (checked):
[image]

However, **if I draw a UIBarButtonItem to my toolbar, these fields are not shown**.

Does this mean that a toolbar cannot be customized depending on size classes?

Answer (score 0):

Briefly speaking, size classes, or vary for traits, only work for `UIView` objects, but `UIBarItem`/`UIBarButtonItem` inherits from `NSObject`, not `UIView`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This might be the solution, but I was not able to find anything in the docs that says that size classes apply only to `UIView` subclasses. Do you have a reference?